# submit for approval button on standard task object

Tags: approval-process

Why there is no standard Submit for approval button in Task Object. How to create custom Submit for approval button and relate it to Approval process?

Answer (score 1):

The Task(Activity/Event) object does not work with the Salesforce Approval Process. That is why you're unable to add a submit for approval button to this objects page layouts.

I can't find Salesforce documentation that states this, however, I speak from experience and here is a 9 year old idea on the success community: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrQCAA0

Comment: Do you have any links to documentation you can point to to back up your claims?

Comment: I've updated my answer, however, I can't find any documentation from Salesforce stating it.

Comment: Yeah, linking to an Idea is legit if it seems to clearly answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the Approval apps on AppExchange that make use of their own datamodel. They usually support approvals on any object.

E.g. Approvals Pro https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FMcp7UAD&tab=e has this functionality.

*(full disclosure: I'm affiliated with Approvals Pro)*